# Are there any applications that allow us to ask/answer stack exchange questions from the desktop?

Tags: support, stackexchange, applications

I am looking for an application that acts as a stack exchange client, typically on the desktop.

Features:

- Can ask/edit questions
- Can answer questions
- Can comment
- Supports MathJax

Nice to have's:

- Support for close/open/delete/flag questions
- User stats page
- Moderator tools
- Offline support

I am interested in applications that run on any of the following systems:

- Windows 7
- Mac OS X
- iPhone
- iPad
- Ubuntu

Comment: I predict answers suggesting site-specific web browsers.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a browser?

Comment: You should take a look at [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com) where this question belongs. The answer is that the API is for read-only access. The ability to write may be made available in the future.

Comment: Why was this migrated on meta? :-)

Comment: @Skliwz - Meta is for questions regarding the site itself, which fits this question perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Not currently as the API is read-only, so any desktop apps would only have read-only functionality.

Comment: The API is merely one of the possible ways of interacting with the site.

Comment: @Sklivvz It is the only acceptable way of interacting with the site. Anything else will and has been banned with the release of the API, and since the site uses OpenId, having an application interact with the correct permission is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

> am looking for an application that acts as a stack exchange client, typically on the desktop.

If you're using Chrome, Chrome Menu → Tools → Create application Shortcut.

Comment: If you aren't using Chrome - well start using it :)